# How to use pytest parametrize with inputs that need to be modified?

Tags: python, pytest

Most examples I've seen show a simple case where inputs/outputs can be expressed in a line:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

How should I go about parameters that require a line or two of modifications?
ex:

```py
test_input1 = User()
test_input1.name = 'John'

test_input2 = User()
test_input2.phone = '1234567890'
test_input2.address = '123 Main St'

test_input3 = User()
test_input3.initials.middle = 'A'

test_input4 = User()
test_input4.make_super_user()
```

Let's assume I'm not able to pass these as constructor params, so `User(name='John')` is not an option.

Comment: Make a factory function that does it? E.g. `def create_user(**attrs): user = User(); for attr, value in attrs.items(): setattr(user, attr, value); return user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. Provide the information needed to setup the objects, then do the setup in the test function.  This is a little cumbersome for your specific examples, where the setup doesn't follow a regular pattern, but it still works:

   ```
   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
           'params', [
               dict(
                   name='John',
               ),
               dict(
                   phone='1234567890',
                   address='123 Main St',
               ),
               dict(
                   initials=dict(middle='A'),
               ),
               dict(
                   is_super_user=True,
               ),
           ]
   )
   def test_user(params):
       user = User()

       if 'name' in params:
           user.name = params['name']

       if 'phone' in params:
           user.phone = params['phone']

       if 'address' in params:
           user.phone = params['address']

       if 'initials' in params:
           user.initials.middle = params['initials']['middle']

       if params.get('is_super_user')
           user.make_super_user()

       assert ...
   ```
2. Parametrize the test function with factory functions.  This idea is a little different than what jonrsharpe was suggesting in the comments, because in this case you'd write a separate factory for each test case.  That said, you could cut down on boilerplate for examples 1 and 2 by writing a "factory factory" using code similar to jonrsharpe's:

   ```
   def make_user_with_name():
       user = User()
       user.name = 'John'
       return user

   def make_user_with_phone_address():
       user = User()
       user.phone = '1234567890'
       user.address = '123 Main St'
       return user

   def make_user_with_middle_initial():
       user = User()
       user.initial.middle = 'A'
       return user

   def make_super_user():
       user = User()
       user.make_super_user()
       return user

   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
           'factory', [
               make_user_with_name,
               make_user_with_phone_address,
               make_user_with_middle_initial,
               make_super_user,
           ]
   )
   def test_user(factory):
       user = factory()
       assert ...
   ```
3. Use `exec()` to create objects from strings.  This is a good approach for when you're loading parameters from a separate file (which is something I highly recommend; see [parametrize_from_file](https://parametrize-from-file.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), although the example below just has everything in python for simplicity.  Note that each snippet is expected to define a global variable named `user`:

   ```
   @pytest.mark.parametrize(
       'snippet', [
               """\
   user = User()
   user.name = 'John'
   """,
               """\
   user = User()
   user.phone = '1234567890'
   user.address = '123 Main St'
   """,
               """\
   user = User()
   user.initials.middle = 'A'
   """,
               """\
   user = User()
   user.make_super_user()
   """,
       ]
   )
   def test_user(snippet):
       scope = {}
       exec(snippet, scope)
       user = scope['user']

       assert ...
   ```

Comment: exec looks appealing, aside from providing params as strings. parametrize_from_file looks like something pytest could adopt.